Widget is missing in iOS 15-18
I created a widget with WidgetKit, it works fine when I run the application from Xcode on the simulator, but it does not find this widget on a real device.
Maybe someone will tell me why?
I tested on real devices with iOS 15.8.3, 18.1.
I tried build on another real device, but I got the same issue.
There my code:
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), emoji: "")
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), emoji: "")
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, emoji: "")
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let emoji: String
}

struct PanicWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Time:")
            Text(entry.date, style: .time)

            Text("Emoji:")
            Text(entry.emoji)
        }
    }
}

struct PanicWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "PanicWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
                PanicWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                    .containerBackground(.fill.tertiary, for: .widget)
            } else {
                PanicWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                    .padding()
                    .background()
            }
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}

import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

@main
struct PanicWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        PanicWidget()
    }
}

Yes, this is the default widget from Apple, but it also only works on the simulator, but on a real device the widget is not found.
I tried all the guides on creating widgets on the network and the situation is the same.
Also I used Console.app to monitor to the relevant processes related to my app and extensions and found these logs - Logs here
I understand this is the reason why I can't find my widget in the search? But why is this so and how to fix it?
Maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!
